# PostageApp Email Issue

Tags: php, postageapp

I am trying to send email to my client as per shown in image with my Postage App Script but unfortunately we are getting following error:-

```
May 24 06:05:07 Transmission Created
May 24 06:05:13 Error: Mismatched Envelope and From Domains
May 24 06:05:13 Failed
```

I checked Postage App docs but didn`t find any solution.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not PostageApp user, but it appears the complaint is that you have a sender address of sender@postageapp.com (domain is postageapp.com) and a from address of whatever domain you are developing.

I would suggest changing the sender email address to something valid (or "no-reply@") from the same domain.

If you have an SPF record for the domain you may also need to add postageapp.com (or the server that will eventually be used) to the record to show that postageapp.com is allowed to send emails for your domain.

Comment: OK, good, but that was a point about a possible later issue regarding rejection by recipient servers; I think the problem is before then and the mail cannot be sent because the sender email address is a default value and apparently must match the from address domain. I know it doesn't have to match according to SMTP rules, but this appears to be a PostageApp requirement.